# Excel - Copy multiple discrete items to clipboard in Win 10

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning / experimenting with VBA in Excel 2013, on Win 10.
I have a list of items in column A. I generate a VBA sub using the macro recorder, aiming to copy several separate items to the Win 10 multi-clipboard. It ends up something like this:

```
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("A7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("A9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

When I single-step through this, it works as intended, that is I end up with the three cell values on the clipboard as separate items.
However, when I run the macro / sub, it only copies the last item.
Can anyone explain this behaviour?
Thanks!

Comment: Imagine the clipboard like a cell. By the copy action your write something to that cell. Then you write something else. In assigning a new value to the cell (clipboard) the previous content is replaced. If you want the clipboard to hold 3 items, you should copy them in a single operation, such as Range("A1:A3").Copy.. In VBA you aren't limited to the clipboard, however, you can also assign the values to a variable, like `MyArray = Range("A1:A3").Value`.

Comment: Hi Variatus, thanks for the reply. I should have been a bit clearer; I want the values on the clipboard so that I can paste them in another Windows application. Plus they are not contiguous. But why does it work fine single-step, but not as a sub?

Comment: What do you do when you do it single step? You probably paste it into the other application and then retun to the debugger in order to do the next step, right? Where is this step ("pasting in the other application") reflected in your code?

Comment: Hi there... no, I single step through the whole sub, and the [n] values are then copied to the clipboard to use wherever I choose to paste them. However, if I run the whole procedure, only the last value is stored - presumably, as Variatus has said, the previous content is overwritten.

Comment: Quite simply, any application in which I can use [Windows]-V and paste from the multi-clipboard.

Comment: I am wondering if a) it is something to do with using Office 2013 - the multi-clipboard wasn't around then or b) the context handling at the point where VB hands back to the editor. I'm no expert, just a newbie - that must be obvious to anybody - and really, this is not that important, it was just an experiment !

Comment: If you hold down the Ctl key while clicking to select the new selection will be added to the previous. In this way you can select non-contiguous cells and then copy them to the clipboard in one operation. Your step-through approach must somehow link into this functionality.

Comment: I stumbled on the solution, sort of. On the 'Home' tab on the ribbon, there is a tiny dropdown button on 'Clipboard', this displays the clipboard. Running the sub/macro then works as expected, collects all the items. With the clipboard not displayed, the sub only collects the last item. Weird !

Answer (score -1):

### Copy Discretely

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyDiscretely()
    Const AddressesList As String = "A1,A7,A9"
    Dim Addresses() As String: Addresses = Split(AddressesList, ",")
    Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(0 To UBound(Addresses))
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(Addresses)
        arr(n) = CStr(Range(Addresses(n)).Value)
    Next n
    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .SetText Join(arr, vbLf)
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008, I'll play around with that.